# I have setup EFK stack with Xpack security enabled it worked great until one of the Elasticsearch pods restarted

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, efk

When one of the elasticsearch pods restarts for any reason, in kibana logs I was getting error that the elastic user was not able to authenticate . I could not able to find any relevant documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

my kibana log:

{"type":"error","@timestamp":"2021-11-02T19:33:54Z","tags":["warning","stats-collection"],"pid":1,"level":"error","error":{"message":"[security_exception] failed to authenticate user [elastic], with { header={ WWW-Authenticate="Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"" } }","name":"Error","stack":"[security_exception] failed to authenticate user [elastic], with { header={ WWW-Authenticate="Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"" } } :: {"path":"/.kibana_task_manager/_search","query":{"ignore_unavailable":true},"body":"{\"sort\":[{\"task.runAt\":\"asc\"},{\"_id\":\"desc\"}],\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"type\":\"task\"}},{\"bool\":{\"filter\":{\"term\":{\"_id\":\"Maps-maps_telemetry\"}}}}]}}}","statusCode":401,"response":"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to authenticate user [elastic]\",\"header\":{\"WWW-Authenticate\":\"Basic realm=\\\"security\\\" charset=\\\"UTF-8\\\"\"}}],\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"failed to authenticate user [elastic]\",\"header\":{\"WWW-Authenticate\":\"Basic realm=\\\"security\\\" charset=\\\"UTF-8\\\"\"}},\"status\":401}","wwwAuthenticateDirective":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}\n    at respond (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:315:15)\n    at checkRespForFailure (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:274:7)\n    at HttpConnector. (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:166:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4929:19)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"},"message":"[security_exception] failed to authenticate user [elastic], with { header={ WWW-Authenticate="Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"" } }"}

now i enabled  xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true and then i am getting this error in es master node

{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-03T19:17:30,962+0000", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.TcpTransport", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master", "cluster.uuid": "hO1sgzRlTKWHl-jJVItUmA", "node.id": "PnVpoMi0TACfs_vJNQ1afQ",  "message": "exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9300, remoteAddress=/SOMEIPADDRESS}], closing connection" ,

Comment: are you using persistent storage for the pods? what is the actual error you are seeing?

Comment: I am not using storage for master or client nodes, but for data node, i have a persistent volume. I have updated the question with kibana logs @MarkWalkom

Comment: you need persistent storage for master nodes, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/modules-node.html#master-node

Comment: thanks i fixed that issue. now I am geeting errors with tls on master node

Comment: is `SOMEIPADDRESS` one of your cluster nodes?

Comment: Yes it is my ES node Ip

Comment: then there's likely something causing a connectivity issue

Comment: I checked the possibilities and couldn't found any, so I did my setup using ECK and it works fine